# Displaying large forms on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ruby, sinatra

I'm currently in the process of toying with a few things at the same time: Heroku, Sinatra, HAML/SASS, and of course the glue: Ruby.  I'm loving that, and it all goes well with DataMapper.  However, my current "project to learn by" seems to be pretty data-intensive.  Though it is also something I *want to have*.

I've been a bit of an amateur thoroughbred handicapper for a while now and I'm compiling a bit of statistics.  Stats which I would love to be able to display on my iphone.

iPhoneUI and iPhone-Universal are great and offer wonderful CSS layout options.

But I'm looking for:

1) Advice on displaying large forms on a small screen such as the iphone.  Do I break it out into sections, "tabs", etc?  I'm a programmer, just not a very good visual designer.  Does anyone have any sample sites I can look at?

Thanks in advance; I hope a few responses can get me through this bit of a "designers block" that I apparently seem to be stuck in.

Answer (score 0):

Organizing forms into a [grouped table view](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/TableViewGrouped.png) is a common design concept. Most long forms in Apple-created apps seem to use them. As an example, take a look at some of the forms inside of the Settings app (some good examples are the form to add a new mail account, connect to VPN, etc.)